# Previewing local Github README.md changes?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

How do I preview changes to README.md in my local client, prior to committing and pushing to Github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com) and create a README.md file.

[image: github gist readme preview]

Now you can write into textarea, and preview changes by clicking on the tab. Note that isn't necessary to commits changes.

Answer (score 1):

See this

Nome: node-readme
ID: bengreenier.vscode-node-readme
Descrição: A vscode extension to view javascript module documentation in editor.
Versão: 3.0.2
Editor: bengreenier
Link do Marketplace do VS: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bengreenier.vscode-node-readme

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You'll require an editor that provides the preview feature or some other third-party tool.